# How to export qmail email accounts

Tags: migration, email, export

I want to migrate a domain to another server. I am using qmail on both servers. Is there a way I could export all the email accounts settings (login, password, redirections, mailing lists, etc, not the emails themselves) ?

Answer (score 1):

It entirely depends on your configuration.  A QMAIL install by itself uses local user accounts, which have one-way hashes for the passwords.  You could parse out the usernames from `/etc/passwd` and the password hashes from `/etc/shadow`.  In all likelihood, you can build the system and copy most of the configuration directly over.

What additional software are you using with your QMAIL installation?  Are there any particular areas you needed more details about?

Comment: I am using qmailadmin. Thanks for the answer so far !